# Procedure to find the largest number in an array of SDWORDS (assembly language)

Tags: arrays, assembly

So I am supposed to find the largest number in an array of signed double words.  My current code seems to break when I try to compare the numbers on the stack.  Can someone point out to me where I am going wrong with this program, as I am new to assembly and am having a hard time understanding it.

my code- http://codepad.org/eneTDVfw

Comment: You need to post your code here. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the link describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Providing the necessary details will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: What assembly compiler are you using? If not microsoft `masm`, then you cannot use `TITLE MASM Template` or `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc` or `END main`.

Comment: Yes, lots of us enjoy helping people just like you; but do follow the regular rules, and post the source code here in your question (not a link to an external site; nobody will give you the time of day). Put it here and watch what you learn ! You'll like it.

Comment: You sure cannot modify your stack in the middle of nowhere... you certainly meant to change ebp, not esp, in the loop.